# htaccess redirect single Wordpress page to new no-Wordpress page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

For a project where I converted an old Wordpress environment to a non-Wordpress environment, I need a redirect of one specific Wordpress page.

For example:

Old (WordPress page)

```
https://www.example.com/news/
```

New (non-WordPress page):

```
https://www.example.com/shop-news.php
```

However, pages in the `/news/` folder are already resolved with a Redirect 301.

```
Redirect 301 /newsitem1/ https://www.example.com/news/2020/newsitem1.php
Redirect 301 /newsitem2/ https://www.example.com/news/2021/newsitem2.php
Redirect 301 /newsitem3/ https://www.example.com/news/2021/newsitem3.php
Etc..
```

The name `/news/` also appears in the new environment, so I have to prevent the redirect rules from changing the new URLs as well.

How can I best solve this in `.htaccess`? I've already tried something with Regex expressions, but I can't figure it out.

I've tried several things with `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. Especially something along the lines of:

`RewriteRule ^news/[some Regex expressions to indicate that it should be 'empty' after the /] shop-news.php [R=301,L]`

Comment: `[some Regex expressions to indicate that it should be 'empty' after the /]` - also known as `$`, the counterpart to the `^` at the start.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of a complete rewrite rule? Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^news/$ shop-news.php [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

To redirect `/news/` only you would need to place the following mod_rewrite directive at the *top* of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress code block, ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section (the order of the directives is important).

```
RewriteRule ^news/$ /shop-news.php [R=301,L]
```

The `$` is an end-of-string anchor, indicating the end of the URL-path.

Note also the `/` (slash) prefix on the *substitution* string. Without the slash prefix, this rule is dependent on the `RewriteBase` directive (usually defined in the WordPress code block later in the file). However, external redirects should rarely be dependent on the `RewriteBase` directive.

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, that occurs later in the file (in the WordPress code block).

Comment: It works!! I was almost there ... Thanks!